# Hide everything outside window HTML jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i made a website, basically first time messing around with jquery.

I have a div **main-container** which contains all the content. This main-slider slides in the window. i'd set it up by doing this in the document.ready function:

```
<script>
$("#main-slider").hide().animate({left:'+=2000', opacity:'0.0'},0);
$("#main-slider").fadeIn(100).animate({left:'-60', opacity:'1.0'},1000);
$("#inhoud").delay(100).animate({left:'-30', opacity:'1.0'},300);
$("#inhoud").delay(20).animate({left:'-5', opacity:'1.0'},300);
$("#main-slider").animate({left:'-40', opacity:'1.0'},150);
</script>
```

On normal browsers (tested with safari, chrome and firefox) it looks like how i want to but on mobile devices it starts zoomed out since the **main-slider** starts animating from `+=2000;`

Is there a way to hide the div when it's not inside the viewport  ?

I made a jsFiddle with a basic concept of what i have, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work tho ;p sorry.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/Edp9J/1/)

A concept version of the website : http://paparashie.nl/woonkans

Comment: after hiding you are animating that's wrong way to do!

Comment: @C-link I'm doing that so that the div starts animating at +=2000. perhaps that's a wrong way to do but it seems to work. Is there a way to hide the div when outside the screen.

Comment: @C-link Could you please provide an example code ? Like i said; i'm pretty new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am understanding correctly, but have you tried with css?

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Apply this to html or body...

JSfiddle is not working, can you attach screenshot to help us see the problem

Comment: On the bottom of my question there's a link to the website.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately not on mobile devices that zoom automatically. You can check the website with your mobile browser : http://paparashie.nl/woonkans